# why xml is called 'eXtensible' markup language?

Tags: xml

All I read about XML is that it is used for storing, carrying, and exchanging data.

But What makes XML extensible in nature unlike html? And what does this 'eXtensible' stands for?

Comment: Voted to close this as off topic, I think this is more of a question for google.

Comment: 'off topic'? I believe this question genuinely comes to the mind of any beginner when hearing 'XML' for the first time. I am surprised I didn't find any SO question regarding this to understand it a bit in depth.

Comment: It's off topic because it is not a programming question. It's not relevant on stackoverflow. This is more suited to a google search. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=why+is+xml+called+extensible&rlz=1C1MSNA_enGB666GB666&oq=why+is+XML+cal&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j69i60l3j0.4791j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: It's weird, the first link wasn't showing up when I googled from my country

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about the history of some particular terminology, not a question about programming. (Try a question on the xml-dev forum at xml.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is not a programming question. But i guess it still has somethin to do with programming.

The Difference Between XML and HTML were designed with different goals:

- HTML was designed to display data - with focus on how data looks
- HTML works with predefined tags like <\p>, <\h1>, <\table>, etc.
- XML was designed to carry data - with focus on what data is
- XML tags are not predefined like HTML tags are
- XML Does Not Use Predefined Tags
- The XML language has no predefined tags. The tags are not defined in any XML standard. The tags are "invented" by the author of the XML document.
- With XML, the author must define both the tags and the document structure.

So you can't really compare the Extensible from XML to HTML because you use the languages in different ways. And XML isn't called Extensible because it is the most Extensible language, it is simply Extensible.

**XML is Extensible because most XML applications will work as expected even if new data is added (or removed).**

Imagine an application designed to display the original version of note.xml (<\to> <\from> <\heading> <\data>).

Then imagine a newer version of note.xml with added <\date> and <\hour> elements, and a removed <\heading>.
The way XML is constructed, older version of the application can still work